# htaccess - Stop processing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force https on our order page and at the same time use standard http for the other pages on the site. And finally then make a internal rewrite so all requests is handled by index.php

This is what I have tried so far but my problem is that after the last RewriteRule to index.php all the rules a processed once again and the second RewriteUrl is processed since (I guess) the internal url no longer is /sv/webshop/ and I end up with something like http://www.yyyyy/?language=sv&_url=/webshop/

I have tried adding the flag END to the last RewriteUrl but then I got a Internal Server Error.

Is it possible to stop the processing or is there another solution?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/sv/webshop/)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://yyyyyy.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/sv/webshop/)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://yyyyyy.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(sv|dk|no|en|de)/(.*)$ index.php?language=$1&_url=/$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Use the L flag on the last rule. `[QSA,L]`

Comment: Thanks, but the L flag stops processing the rewrite rules for that request. It will then make a new request for the new, rewritten filename and begin processing the rewrite rules again.

Comment: Where exactly is your .htaccess file? In the root or  `/sv/webshop/`?

Comment: It's located in the root. The folder structure /sv/webshop/ does not exist since all calls is handled by index.php also in the root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way, I'm not sure this is the best solution but it works. Please let me know if there is a better solution. This is what I do for now

```
# Placed before any the of the other rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)language(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,L]
```